# Развертывание приложения Node.js + MSSQL

Tags: node.js, sql-server, развертывание

Уважаемые программисты! Как-то недавно занимался разработкой первого node.js приложения, данные которого лежат в двух базах данных в MSSQL. Стало интересно, есть ли бесплатные хостинги, на котором я бы мог развернуть свое приложение? В интернете информации не нашел... Если ли нет бесплатных, то можно предложить и платные. Спасибо заранее за помощь!

Comment: как-то очень плохо вы искали...первая же ссылка ведет на https://www.gearhost.com/

Comment: c mssql вам на azure скорее всего ($$$). с mysql проще будет найти.

Comment: Благодарю за ответы, позже рассмотрю оба варианта